# Read CSV file in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, d3.js, sankey-diagram

I have this CSV file:

```
source,xpos,target,value
user1,0,user2,4
user2,1,user3,4
user1,,0,user3,2
user5,user4,2
```

and Im tring to read it in a script

```
d3.csv("sankey.csv", function(error, data){

graph = {"nodes" : [], "links" : []};

data.forEach(function (d) {
  graph.nodes.push({ "name": d.source });
   graph.nodes.push({ "xPos": d.xPos });
  graph.nodes.push({ "name": d.target });

  graph.links.push({ "source": d.source,
                     "target": d.target,
                     "value": +d.value });



 });


 graph.nodes = d3.keys(d3.nest()
   .key(function (d) { return d.name; })
   .map(graph.nodes));



    graph.links.forEach(function (d, i) {
   graph.links[i].source = graph.nodes.indexOf(graph.links[i].source);
   graph.links[i].target = graph.nodes.indexOf(graph.links[i].target);
 });



 graph.nodes.forEach(function (d, i) {
   graph.nodes[i] = { "name": d };
 });


graph.nodes.forEach(function (d, i) {  // HOW CAN I REACH THE VALUE
   graph.nodes[i] = { "xPos": graph.nodes.xPos };
 });
```

the question is how i can read the value of the xPos,beside that the xPos is actually a one of the Node properties to specify later on the position on X axis.

Comment: Check the capital P: you wrote `xpos` on the data but `xPos` on the function.
Also, the last row is not correct, there is a `xpos` missing between source and target.

Comment: And I just saw the third row as well, two commas... is this the real CSV or just an example?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado dont you hate it when you help people and they just dont reply, smh :(

Comment: @thisOneGuy welcome to my world!

Comment: @GerardoFurtado it is just an example i was trying to explain, and sry for been late to answer , anyway i know that is the last row aint correct but i dont know how to set the property  xPos foreach one of the nodes ..

Comment: No worries... so, your CSV is correctly formatted, right?

Comment: yes, i did it before with JSON file and the form was like this :code { "nodes":[ {"node":0,"name":"node0","xPos":0}, {"node":1,"name":"node1","xPos":0}, {"node":2,"name":"node2","xPos":1}, {"node":3,"name":"node3","xPos":2}, {"node":4,"name":"node4","xPos":3} ], "links":[ {"source":0,"target":2,"value":2}, {"source":1,"target":2,"value":2}, {"source":1,"target":3,"value":2}, {"source":0,"target":4,"value":2}, {"source":2,"target":3,"value":2}, {"source":2,"target":4,"value":2}, {"source":3,"target":4,"value":4}] }code 

and now im trying to change it to CSV.
@GerardoFurtado

Comment: @Chis, It seems to me that, in the moment you use `graph.nodes = d3.keys(d3.nest()` there is no more `graph.nodes.xPos`. That's why you can't read the value of xPos, and it's returning "undefined".

Comment: @GerardoFurtado it's the only way that i know to manipulate an array

Comment: The best idea is to create your own JSON, based on the CSV, pushing the objects inside the arrays. I saw that you just asked another question about this, let's hope the guys over there answer you!

Comment: ya well im trying many solutions at the same time. 
Anyway thanx @GerardoFurtado